# How to integrate C++ into Android Java application?

Tags: java, android, c++

I want to use C++ to run a service in the background, that will process an image.  However I can't write the whole app in C++ because it is a collaborative project, how would I go about creating an android service in C++ and then calling/running it from the java written application?

Comment: have you had a look at the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)?

Comment: Because it's collaborative? Why not get rid of your friends and make new ones who speak C++? A profitable long-term investment, too.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html)

Bear in mind I haven't tried to do anything with Android or the Android API however this is my experience working with JNI for a Linux ARM chip running an embedded version of Java 8.

You will need to cross compile whatever C++ files you want to use for the android os. When you package your JAR to run on the Andrioid device you will need to include the compiled binary files which you can statically link to. You can call C++ methods from Java using native methods and you can store a pointer to the JVM in your C++ program and make callbacks to methods from C++.

If you are using something like maven to package your project there are plugins that will do this for you automatically.

Here's the configuration we are using to compile for an embedded Linux operating system. (You'll have to modify this for your own purposes)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <javahOS>linux</javahOS>
        <jdkIncludePath>${embeddedJDKIncludePath}</jdkIncludePath>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>javah</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                <!-- trigger javah execution -->
                <javahClassNames>
                    <javahClassName> LIST CLASS NAMES </javahClassName>
                </javahClassNames>
                <javahOS>linux</javahOS
                <javahOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/include</javahOutputDirectory>
                <javahProvider>default</javahProvider>
                <javahVerbose>true</javahVerbose>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>javah</goal>
                </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You'll of course want to replace the `LIST CLASS NAMES` with the actual list of classes you want to generate C++ JNI bindings for.

You can then declare classes like so:

```
class RunService extends JNIWrapper {
    public native boolean runService();
    //More methods if you want. You can pass pretty much anything back 
    //and forth between native code.
}
```

You'll also need to write the JNIWrapper class that loads in the C++ files. This JNIWrapper file can look something like this.

```
static
{
    try
    {
        if( !libraryLoaded )
        {
            // create temporary file
            jniLibrary = File.createTempFile([name of some temporary file]);
            // flag for delete on exit
            jniLibrary.deleteOnExit();

            byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int readBytes;

            InputStream is = JNIWrapper.class.getResourceAsStream([link to directory inside your compiled JAR where your C++ binary has been placed]);

            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(jniLibrary);

            try
            {
                while((readBytes = is.read(buffer)) != -1 )
                {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                os.close();
                is.close();
            }


            libraryLoaded = true;
        }

        System.load(jniLibrary.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Approximately, yes.  But the details are mostly wrong, including everything you have in code blocks.  Android does not use a JVM, and libraries are dynamically linked, not statically.